# Django: Setting context by url's GET

Tags: django, django-context

**How can you make a specific action based on the url by base.html?**

I have two if -clauses as context statements in base.html. If there is algebra in the GET, then the given context should be shown.

## My url.conf

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^algebra/$', 'algebra'),
    (r'^mathematics/$', 'mathematics'),

)
```

**My base.html in pseudo-code**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
  <body>
              {% if algebra %}                                    
                  <div>... -- do this -- </div> 
              {% endif %}

              {% if math %}
                  <div>... -- do this -- </div>
              {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to Ned's variable-value-based method is to use two different templates that extend a common base template. E.g.

In templates/base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
  <body>
      {% block main_body %}                                    
      {% endblock main_body %}                                    
       etc., etc.
```

Then have your algebra view use templates/algebra.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block main_body %}
  do algebra stuff here
{% end block main_body %}
```

and do something similar for `math` or whatever. Each approach has advantages and disadvantages. Pick the one that feels like the best fit to your problem.

**Update:** You pass `"algebra.html"` as the first argument to `render_to_response()`. It *extends* `"base.html"` in that it uses all of it *except* for the block(s) it explicitly replaces. See [Template Inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#id1) for an explanation of how this works. Template inheritance is a *very* powerful concept for achieving a consistent look and feel across a large number of pages which differ in their body, but share some or all of the menus, etc. *And* you can do multi-level template inheritance which is extremely nice for managing sites that have subsections which have significant differences with the "main look" and yet want to share as much HTML/CSS as possible.

This is a key principle in [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/#don-t-repeat-yourself-dry) in the template world.

Comment: What is your view -method? Is it `def common_view(request): ctx = Context(); return_to_response("base.html", ctx)` ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't show your view functions, but here's a simple structure:

```
def algebra(request):
    return common_view(request, algebra=True)

def math(request):
    return common_view(request, math=True)

def common_view(request, math=False, algebra=False):
    ctx = Context()
    ctx['algebra'] = algebra
    ctx['math'] = math
    # blah blah, all the other stuff you need in the view...
    return render_to_response("base.html", ctx)
```

(I might have some typos, it's off the top of my head).